# How can I search through a string in C# and replace areas bounded by a pattern?

Tags: c#

We tried a few solutions now that try and use XML parsers. All fail because the strings are not always 100% valid XML.  Here's our problem.

We have strings that look like this:

```
var a = "this is a testxxx of my data yxxx and of these xxx parts yxxx";
var b = "hello testxxx world yxxx ";

"this is a testxxx3yxxx and of these xxx1yxxx";
"hello testxxx1yxxx ";
```

The key here is that we want to do something to the data between xxx and yxxx. In the example above I would need a function that counts words and replaces the strings with a word count.

Is there a way we can process the string a and apply a function to change the data that's between the xxx and yxxx? Any function right now as we're just trying to get an idea of how to code this.

Comment: might be a silly suggestion, by why not split the string on xxx (or any other delimiter), which will fetch you all strings between xxx, and then you can change them and resconstruct the string.

Comment: But I thought regex handled only one regular expression. What I need is to find each one and then do something to the part that matches.

Comment: but the string area is bounded by xxx yxxx to signal start and end of pattern. We thought of split but we are not sure how to apply this because there are more than one inner matching string.

Comment: The data between xxx and yxxx is always the same?

Comment: data between xxx and yxxx could be anything.

Comment: I updated the question. Hope it make it more clear. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Split` method:

```
 var parts = a.Split(new[] {"xxx", "yxxx"}, StringSplitOptions.None)
            .Select((s, index) =>
                {
                    string s1 = index%2 == 1 ? string.Format("{0}{2}{1}", "xxx", "yxxx", s + "1") : s;
                    return s1;
                });

  var result = string.Join("", parts);
```

Comment: This seems to work. How can I join up the result to make it into a string?

Answer (score 3):

If it always going to xxx and yxxx, you can use regex as suggested.

```
var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
Regex regex = new Regex("xxx(.*?)yxxx");
var splitGroups = Regex.Match(a);

foreach(var group in splitGroups)
{
    var value  = splitGroupsCopy[i];

    // do something to value and then append it to string builder

   stringBuilder.Append(string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", "xxx", value, "yxxx")); 

}
```

I suppose this is as basic as it gets.

Comment: But the split is on xxx ... yxxxx   and how can I change this code and then put it all back together again?

Comment: That would also take into account the string parts that are between 'yxxx' and 'xxx'. Which is not part of the needed data.

Comment: @Flater - still need the data

Comment: @tranceporter. With the regex solution how could I tie all of the matching strings together. What I need is when I match a string then I will do some processing of the string and replace it with new data. The data before and after all the strings is still needed.

Answer (score 1):

The `indexOf()` function will return to you the index of the first occurrence of a given substring.

(My indices might be a bit off, but) I would suggest doing something like this:

```
var searchme = "this is a testxxx of my data yxxx and there are many of these xxx parts yxxx";

var startindex= searchme.indexOf("xxx");
var endindex = searchme.indexOf("yxxx") + 3; //added 3 to find the index of the last 'x' instead of the index of the 'y' character

var stringpiece = searchme.substring(startindex, endindex - startindex);
```

and you can repeat that while `startindex != -1`

Like I said, the indices might be slightly off, you might have to add a +1 or -1 somewhere, but this will get you along nicely (I think).

---

Here is a little sample program that counts chars instead of words. But you should just need to change the processor function.

```
var a = "this is a testxxx of my data yxxx and there are many of these xxx parts yxxx";
a = ProcessString(a, CountChars);


string CountChars(string a)
{
    return a.Length.ToString();
}

string ProcessString(string a, Func<string, string> processor)
{
    int idx_start, idx_end = -4;
    while ((idx_start = a.IndexOf("xxx", idx_end + 4)) >= 0)
    {
        idx_end = a.IndexOf("yxxx", idx_start + 3);
        if (idx_end < 0)
            break;

        var string_in_between = a.Substring(idx_start + 3, idx_end - idx_start - 3);
        var newString = processor(string_in_between);

        a = a.Substring(0, idx_start + 3) + newString + a.Substring(idx_end, a.Length - idx_end);

        idx_end -= string_in_between.Length - newString.Length;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance Nico ;) Although I would suspect the 'xxx' and 'yxxx' parts should be included in the string that is extracted, to facilitate a string replace if that needs to be done later on :-) But nice little snippet!

Comment: Also, `idx_end = a.IndexOf("xxx", idx_start + 3);` should be `idx_end = a.IndexOf("yxxx", idx_start + 3);`. I think you missed the 'y' character there.

Comment: I understand your first code but the sample doesn't seem to take into account that the string to be changed is between an "xxx" and a "yxxx".

Comment: Is there a way that I can tie this all together because I still need to get the code outside of the "xxx ... yxxx" and then do something to the code inside the "xxx ... yxxx" ?

Comment: It all depends on what your mean by "do something to the code". Will it be processed, then followed by a string replace? (Also, for the sample, you'll have to ask Nico Schertler, he added it :)) My snippet is a bit more rudimentary, it needs some checking of indices and an iteration. But I can't really say which one is best because it depends on what you need to do with the found string.

Comment: Yes, you can. Before computing idx_end, you can get the substring from the last idx_end and current idx_start. Btw, I corrected the xxx...yxxx part.

Comment: Hello Nice and Flater. I updated my question. Here I give an example of a function that I might use to count the words within the sample string. I hope it makes more sense. Yes the string needs to be processed and I need a string replace if that is possible. Sorry I was not so clear with my question.

Comment: Well the answer is pretty much already there. Just replace this line of code: `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string_in_between);` with any string manipulation you want to do on the `string_in_between`, then put it back in the original datastring. This will repeat itself while it keeps finding substring delimited by 'xxx' and 'yxxx'.

Answer (score 1):

Using Regex.Replace will replace all the matches with your choice of text, something like this:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex("xxx.+yxxx");
string cleaned = rgx.Replace(a, "replacementtext");
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will process each of the parts delimited by "xxx". It preserves the "xxx" separators. If you do not want to preserve the "xxx" separators, remove the two lines that say "result.Append(separator);".

Given:

```
"this is a testxxx of my data yxxx and there are many of these xxx parts yxxx"
```

It prints:

```
"this is a testxxx>> of my data y<<xxx and there are many of these xxx>> parts y<<xxx"
```

I'm assuming that's the kind of thing you want. Add your own processing to "processPart()".

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string text = "this is a testxxx of my data yxxx and there are many of these xxx parts yxxx";
            string separator = "xxx";
            var result = new StringBuilder();

            int index = 0;

            while (true)
            {
                int start = text.IndexOf(separator, index);

                if (start < 0)
                {
                    result.Append(text.Substring(index));
                    break;
                }

                result.Append(text.Substring(index, start - index));

                int end = text.IndexOf(separator, start + separator.Length);

                if (end < 0)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Unbalanced separators.");
                }

                start += separator.Length;

                result.Append(separator);
                result.Append(processPart(text.Substring(start, end-start)));
                result.Append(separator);

                index = end + separator.Length;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }

        private static string processPart(string part)
        {
            return ">>" + part + "<<";
        }
    }
}
```

[EDIT] Here's the code amended to work with two different separators:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string text = "this is a test<pre> of my data y</pre> and there are many of these <pre> parts y</pre>";
            string separator1 = "<pre>";
            string separator2 = "</pre>";
            var result = new StringBuilder();

            int index = 0;

            while (true)
            {
                int start = text.IndexOf(separator1, index);

                if (start < 0)
                {
                    result.Append(text.Substring(index));
                    break;
                }

                result.Append(text.Substring(index, start - index));

                int end = text.IndexOf(separator2, start + separator1.Length);

                if (end < 0)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Unbalanced separators.");
                }

                start += separator1.Length;

                result.Append(separator1);
                result.Append(processPart(text.Substring(start, end-start)));
                result.Append(separator2);

                index = end + separator2.Length;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }

        private static string processPart(string part)
        {
            return "|" + part + "|";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Matthew. Thanks. I will look into this. Btw does it make a difference or how could I adapt this as my sample area is delimited by "xxx yxxx". Actually in the real world it's <pre> and </pre> but I was trying to make it simple for this question and I want an answer that does not depend on XML parsing as there are chances my document will not be valid XML.

Comment: You would need to use two different separators, and increment the indices by the length of the correct separator. I think you should be able to see where to change the code. You should really have specified that in the OP though!

Answer (score 1):

I would use [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) Groups:

Here my solution to get the parts in the string:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> GetParts( string searchFor, string begin, string end ) {
    string exp = string.Format("({0}(?<searchedPart>.+?){1})+", begin, end);
    Regex regex = new Regex(exp);
    MatchCollection matchCollection = regex.Matches(searchFor);
    foreach (Match match in matchCollection) {
        Group @group = match.Groups["searchedPart"];
        yield return @group.ToString();
    }
}
```

you can use it like to get the parts:

```
string a = "this is a testxxx of my data yxxx and there are many of these xxx parts yxxx";

IEnumerable<string> parts = GetParts(a, "xxx", "yxxx");
```

To replace the parts in the original String you can use the Regex Group to determine Length and StartPosition (@group.Index, @group.Length).